# Where should i mention copyright permission in store listing?

Tags: android, copyright-display

I have received permission from the copyrighted image's owner to use the image in my android application. **Now where should i mention that permission in store listing while publishing??** i.e how to let google know that i got the permission for the image usage.Thanks in advance!!